Proving $r(t) \to 0$ for a spiral
This is a problem from Ted Shifrin's book on Differential Geometry; consider the spiral $\vec{\alpha} (t) = {r}(t)(\cos t, \sin t)$ where $r(t)$ is a $C^1$ function bounded between $[0,1]$. Characterize (in terms of the existence of improper integral(s)) the functions ${r}(t)$ for which $\vec{\alpha}(t)$ has
finite length on $[0,∞)$ and use this to prove that if $\vec{\alpha}(t)$ has finite length on $[0, ∞)$, then: $$\lim_{t \to ∞} r(t)=0$$
Firstly, $\dfrac{d\vec{\alpha}}{dt}=(r'(t)\cos t - r(t) \sin t)\hat{i} + (r'(t)\sin t + r(t) \cos t ) \hat{j}$ so the expression for arc length is
$$L=\int_0^∞ \sqrt{(r'(t)\cos t - r(t) \sin t)^2+(r'(t)\sin t + r(t) \cos t )^2}dt=\int_0^∞ \sqrt{r(t)^2+r'(t)^2}dt$$.
How do I deduce the second part from this? I cannot claim with certainty that the argument of the radical is monotonically decreasing on $[0, ∞)$ or deduce the asymptote from any convergence test. I looked at finite length of a spiral, which is based off the same problem but I didn't understand how to convert the reasoning into a formal proof; why can't $r(t)$ be an oscillatory function therein?
Edit: Progress after reading the comments -
I get why $\int_0^∞ r'(t) dt$ converges and, thus the limit $\lim_{t \to ∞}r(t)$ exists. This solves my oscillatory function doubt and completes one half of the question. Now, how do I show that this limit is zero, if it exists? I think the argument relies on the fact that if the limit is non-zero i.e. it is in some interval $(r_0 - \epsilon, r_0+ \epsilon), \epsilon>0, r_0 \in (0,1)$ in the neighborhood of infinity, then the integral must diverge (this intuitively makes sense as area under the curve will be something like $r_0 \times ∞$) which produces a contradiction, but how do I formalize this?

If $r$ has not a $0$ limit at $\infty$, then $\exists a>0 \forall b>0 \exists x>b / \left|f(x)\right|>a$. For the length to be finite, this value can only be reached on small intervals, which requires the derivative to be high. Only a hint hence only a comment and not an answer ;-)

So I have to sketch a proof by contradiction relying on the continuity/boundness of the first derivative?

I think you have to complete the first part of the question first. In order for $L$ to exist, what can you say about the improper integrals of $r$ and $|r'|$? Is the condition necessary and sufficient?

Note that $\sqrt{r(t)^2+r'(t)^2}\geq |r(t)|$, and so $$\int^{\infty}_0{\sqrt{r(t)^2+r'(t)^2}}dt \geq \int^{\infty}_0{|r(t)|}dt$$ How does the value of the limit affect this lower bound of arc length?

Note that $r\ge 0$, so oscillation is not the issue.

Perhaps the wrong forum, but huge fan of your book, it is helping me a lot in math class, thank you very much!
